# Processing all 'vardefine's before using the variable as a template parameter

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm attempting to transclude this progress bar template at the top of a Mediawiki page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Template:Progress_Bar.

The template can be used with the parameters 'min', 'max' and 'current'. There are 'max' items I would like to cover/write about on this page and I would like to increment 'current' directly after each complete item.

**Attempt at a solution:** I tried to do this using the *Variables* and *ParseFunctions* extensions, by defining a variable called 'current'. However, since I transclude the template at the top and update the variable farther down, the template only sees the initial value of the variable.

So I am now wondering if I can change the order of processing to process all variables first and the transcludes later. Or maybe there is another way of solving this problem that I haven't thought of.

My knowledge of Mediawiki is minimal.

Comment: From the extension docs, it seems like you need `#var_final`?

Comment: Thanks @Tgr. I must have overlooked that. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem since, as the docs say: "this function can't be used in other functions, expecting the right value is being used". I tried it out and it breaks the progress bar.